python vscode venv - launches in "wrong" directory only on the initial launch
I've got a python project set up with a standard virtual environment (.venv).
When I launch the project in VSCode's debugger for the FIRST time, it detects that the venv has not been activated, and does the source call to the activate script.
However, somewhere it does NOT call the cwd/cd that is specified in the launch.json config file within VSCode.  This makes the initial launch of the debugger fail, because it's in the "wrong" directory when we call the actual script with whatever arguments I'm trying to run for the debug.
machine:~/ws/gitz > source /ws/lwobker-rtp/gitz/powerInventory/.venv/bin/activate
(.venv) machine:~/ws/gitz >  /usr/bin/env /ws/lwobker-rtp/gitz/powerInventory/.venv/bin/python /ws/lwobker-rtp/.vscode-server/extensions

## note, no "cd whatever" call in here???

On all SUBSEQUENT calls to the debugger, I can see that the debug launcher does call the cd <whatever> and the terminal changes into the 'correct' directory and everything runs fine.
(.venv) machine:~/ws/gitz >  cd /users/lwobker/ws/gitz/powerInventory ; /usr/bin/env /ws/lwobker-rtp/gitz
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

It's not like this is the end of the world, because I just have to basically remember to launch it the first time, wait for it to fail, then launch again.  But it seems like something that "should just work" ...
an example stanza from launch.json looks like this:
        {
            "name": "dumpsnap script",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "cwd": "/users/lwobker/ws/gitz/powerInventory",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "dumpsnap.py",
            "args":  ["-f", "some_file"],
        },


You could try to add a preLaunchTask suck as "preLaunchTask": "Activate venv" to your launch.json to ensure the environment is activated before any script is run.
